# Accessing parent property in javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm new to JS and have a question about inheritance. How are inherited properties accessed through the child class?

Lets say I have the following classes:

```
function ParentClass(parentArg) {
    this.parentProperty = parentArg;
}

function ChildClass(childArg1, childArg2) {
    this.prototype = new ParentClass(childArg1);
    this.childProperty = childArg2;
}
```

And at some point an object is created of ChildClass, like so:

```
var foo = new ChildClass('value 1', 'value 2');
```

Then how can a parent property be accessed from the instance of the child? The following returns 'undefined'.

```
var parentValue = foo.parentProperty;
```

Much appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to initialize the `parentProperty`, you have to do it like this

```
function ParentClass(parentArg) {
    this.parentProperty = parentArg;
}

function ChildClass(childArg1, childArg2) {
    ParentClass.call(this, childArg1);
    this.childProperty = childArg2;
}
```

And to actually inherit Parent't methods, you might want to do

```
ChildClass.prototype = Object.create(ParentClass.prototype);
```

After making these changes,

```
var foo = new ChildClass('value 1', 'value 2');
console.log(foo);
# { parentProperty: 'value 1', childProperty: 'value 2' }
```

Answer (score 0):

`foo.prototype.parentProperty` If you want to get `value 1` back

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, I hope that this is not the answer. Otherwise the much more complex pattern that I am planning would be very awkward. This would not be inheritance but composition instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you can't assign to a prototype property before the object definition is declared:

**Doesn't work:**

```
function Parent() {
    this.parentProperty = "test";
}

function Child() {
  // This doesn't work because the prototype is set inside of the definition
  this.prototype = new Parent();
}

var child = new Child();
alert(child.parentProperty);
```

**Works**

```
function Parent() {
    this.parentProperty = "test";
}

function Child() {
    // Define prototype outside of function constructor
}
Child.prototype = new Parent();

var child = new Child();    
alert(child.parentProperty);
```

**Also notice that in the second example we assign to Child.prototype and not new Child().prototype**

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. How would you pass an argument from the child ctor to the parent ctor?

Comment: A parent ctor could require an argument that is received through the child ctor. But I already got the answer for that. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

For ES6, you use extends, eg

```
class A { prop = "prop" } 
class B extends A{} 
new B();
```